# Lead history Report Problem

Tags: reporting

In Field History tracking of Leads , i am tracking 4 fields:- Field1,Field2,Field3,Field4

Then I created a Lead history report with filter criteria as below :
Field / Event equals Field2

Now when i run report and If record1's field2 has been edited twice but values of other fields were different while field2 was changing,still it will show latest values of all other fields other than Field2.

**Actual** :-

RecordName    Field1     Field2     Field3     Field4
Rec1           **A5           B1         C4         D4**
Rec1           A5           B3         C4         D4

**Expected** :-

RecordName    Field1     Field2     Field3     Field4
Rec1           **A1          B1         C1         D1**
Rec1           A5          B3         C4         D4

In short in lead history report it will show latest values of all other fields but i want to see actual values of those fields when that change happened.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: the report should show one line per field changed -- perhaps update OP with screen shots

Comment: Yes...It is showing 1 row per change in field2 value. i.e. from B0 to B1  and then B1 to B3.   But problem is other field values when first change happened (B0 to B1) get overridden when 2nd change happens (B1 to B3) in report.

Comment: Screenshot of Report including filters would be helpful here

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, especially the bit about "*it will show latest values of all other fields other than Field2*"...

So you're filtering the report on "Field2" changes in Lead History. But what you have added to the report columns is Field1 - Field4 from the Lead itself. So of course that's what will happen, Salesforce will show you the most recent values on the Lead record.

You're looking for changes that happened around the same time "Field2" was changed. Something like this, if only I was able to drag the "New value" inside the grid? So instead of ones and zeroes it will show actual value for each field?

[image]

What you want probably can be achieved with Apex & Visualforce, some clever plotting of two queries for example...

```
Set<Id> ids = new Map<Id, Lead>([SELECT Id FROM Lead WHERE Id IN (SELECT LeadId FROM LeadHistory WHERE Field = 'created')]).keyset().clone();
List<LeadHistory> histories = [SELECT LeadId, CreatedDate, Field, NewValue
FROM LeadHistory
WHERE LeadId IN :ids];
```

No idea if there's a way to do something like that in normal report. Out of the box the "New value" can't be dragged into the grid.

What if you would:

1. identify all LeadHistory changes that mention field2
2. make note of their LeadId & date.
3. Query all LeadHistory changes that match same LeadId & date
4. Save that to helper object that has matching Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4 (so flatten 4 histories into 1 custom record)
5. Run a report based on that helper object?

Should be fairly easy to write an apex batch like that. Maybe even possible to do it with Analytic Snapshot (no coding required).

Actually, going forward you could simply detect change of Field2 (with trigger or Process Builder) and create this helper custom object record with Lead's latest values every time it happens. But for existing data you'd still need some kind of data migration to collect old values.